# How do I test a generic type variable for equality with Default(T) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, caching, default-value

I'm trying to write a generic cached property accessor like the following but am getting a compiler error when trying to check whether the storage variable already contains a value:

```
function TMyClass.GetProp<T>(var ADataValue: T; const ARetriever: TFunc<T>): T;
begin
  if ADataValue = Default(T) then // <-- compiler error on this line
    ADataValue := ARetriever();
  Result := ADataValue;
end;
```

The error I'm getting is "E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type".

Would I have to put a constraint on `T` to make this work? The help file says that `Default()` would accept anything except generic types. In my case I'm dealing mostly with simple types like `String`, `Integer` and `TDateTime`.

Or is there some other library function to perform this particular check?

I'm using Delphi 2009 in case that matters.

---

P.S.: Just in case it isn't clear from the code what I'm trying to do: In my case determining the actual property values might take a while for various reasons and sometimes I might not even need them at all. On the plus side however the values are constant so I only want to call the code that determines the actual value the first time that property is accessed and then store the value in a class field and the next time that property is accessed return the cached value directly. Here's an example of how I hoped I would be able to use that code:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FSomeProp: String;
    function GetSomeProp: String;

    function GetProp<T>(var ADataValue: T; const ARetriever: TFunc<T>): T;
  public
    property SomeProp read GetSomeProp;
  end;

function GetSomeProp: String;
begin
  Result := GetProp<String>(FSomeProp,
                            function: String
                            begin
                              Result := SomeSlowOrExpensiveCalculation;
                            end);
end;
```

(obviously, there's more than just one property)

Comment: +1 nice idea by the way.

Comment: You should probably use a nullable type, otherwise the code would constantly re-evaluate properties that are already cached but have the default value. See for example http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/09/18/38869

Comment: @mghie: Good point and usually I would agree but in this particular case the default value can safely always be interpreted as "uninitialized".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a hint in the comments from Binis and digging around a little in Generics.Collections I came up with the following which appears to work just as I wanted it:

```
function TMyClass.GetProp<T>(var ADataValue: T; const ARetriever: TFunc<T>): T;
var
  lComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  lComparer := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  if lComparer.Equals(ADataValue, Default(T)) then
    ADataValue := ARetriever();
  Result := ADataValue;
end;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that "IEqualityComparer" is now within Generics.Defaults (not sure since when, using Berlin 10.1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `Default` function, but the equality operator `=`.

You could constrain `T` to `IEquatable` and use the `Equals` method like this:

```
TMyClass = class
  function GetProp<T : IEquatable<T>>(var ADataValue: T; const ARetriever: 
end;
...
function TMyClass.GetProp<T>(var ADataValue: T; const ARetriever: TFunc<T>): T;
begin  
if ADataValue.Equals (Default(T)) then
  ADataValue := ARetriever();  
Result := ADataValue;
end;
```

Comment: Not sure why but I get an "Undeclared identifier 'IEquatable'" with that code (even though I can see `IEquatable` is indeed declared in System.pas). I would however doubt this would work for me anyways as I am not aware that primitive types like `String`, `TDateTime` or `Integer` somehow implicitly support that interface...

Comment: @Oliver: you're right, you can't use that for primitive types. Unfortunately, I am not aware of another solution. Let's see if others are able to help. I don't know why you get an error message when using `IEquatable`.

Comment: Actually, what is declared in System.pas is not `IEquatable` but `IEquatable<T>` which explains the error... `GetProp<T: IEquatable<T>>(...` does compile but then, as expected,  I get the error when passing `String` for `T`: "Type parameter 'T' must support interface IEquatable<System.string>"