# Delphi : How to filter a Generics collection

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

I want to filter a generics collection like that :

```
var MyListe : TObjectListFilter<TPerson>
[....]
MyListe.Filter("Age", Filter.Equal, 20);
```

Are you an idea for start my generics class ?

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What problems have you come across in your attempts to date?

Comment: https://github.com/malcolmgroves/FluentQuery

Comment: Spring4delphi if I remember also has Tlist.Where(tpredicate) method

Comment: I want to create a generic class and implement a system for filter a collection by criteria on property.

Comment: So take libraries that already have that implemented and read by example how they did it.

Comment: *I want to create a generic class and implement a system for filter a collection by criteria on property.* What is stopping you from doing that? You have to ask a real, actionable question. How I wish we still hard NARQ.

Comment: if you want the interface that you outline - which would necessarily be slow and fragile - you have to learn at least three concepts: Extended RTTI and TValue type and default comparers like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920502 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782333 But it will be slow and fragile. Maybe DelphiDuckDuck lib would also be of some help

Comment: @Arioch'The I've no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Malcolm Groves worked on something like this and wrote and article and published code related to it that should help you: http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=273

Comment: @alcalde that was the second reply to the question :-) However his API is more like Spring4D and not the RTTI-like that topicstarter wants

Comment: @Arioch'The Oops! Sorry I missed that Arioch!

Comment: @Alcalde bet you had a gooood new year holydays :-D

Comment: Ok, thank's for you responses. I will work from your ideas.